# How to prevent anonymous user to use my web service to register in Drupal site?

Tags: web-services, rest, drupal, drupal-7

I created a rest web service on my site, through Drupal Service module. Now, i need it to expose registration to the site for my app to use it, but if i allow anonymous user to do that, is the same that opening spread doors to spammers.

So, how do i prevent anonymous users to use my web service to register? I tried using session authentication but giving it a try, i could register users as anonymous...

Maybe oauth authentication could be helpful? Or using some hook like

```
mymodule_services_resources
```

Obviously i can't prevent anonymous user to register to the website in the canonical way. (which is protected by spam by captcha, which i cannot use, for obvious reasons, in the web service case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the [Services API Key module](https://www.drupal.org/project/services_api_key_auth) could help.